como colocar em campo um dropdown e um input podendo alterar o estado dos dois separadamente
inserir a descrição da imagem aqui
tenho o seguinte campo e preciso selecionar se vai ser < ou > e ao lado o usuario deve digitar o numero que deseja porem ao selecionar o dropdown ele apaga o numero é na hora de salvar ele salva apenas o maior ou menor
codigo: parte html
 {
                    setEditIndex({ index, field: "Gama" });
                    setEditedValue(balanca.Gama || "
                    {editIndex?.index === index && editIndex?.field === "Gama" ? (
                      
                        {/* Dropdown para  */}
                         {
                            const operator = e.target.value; 
                            const number = editedValue?.split(" ")[1] || ""; 
                            setEditedValue(`${operator} ${number}`); 
                          }}
                          onBlur={() => handleConfirmEdit(index, "Gama")}
                          onKeyDown={(e) => e.key === "Enter" && handleConfirmEdit(index, "Gama")}
                          style={{ marginRight: "5px" }}
                          autoFocus
                        >
                          {'
                          ">{'>'}
                        
                    {/* Campo de texto para o número */}
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      value={editedValue?.split(" ")[1] || ""} 
                      onChange={(e) => {
                        const operator = editedValue?.split(" ")[0] || "<"; // Mantém o operador atual
                        const number = e.target.value; 
                        setEditedValue(`${operator} ${number}`);
                      }}
                      onBlur={() => handleConfirmEdit(index, "Gama")}
                      onKeyDown={(e) => e.key === "Enter" && handleConfirmEdit(index, "Gama")}
                      style={{ width: "50px" }}
                    />
                  </div>
                ) : (
                  <div style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}>
                    {/* Exibição do valor */}
                    <span>{balanca.Gama?.split(" ")[0]}</span> {/* Operador */}
                    <span style={{ marginLeft: "5px" }}>{balanca.Gama?.split(" ")[1]}</span> {/* Número */}
                  </div>
                )}
              </td>

funções que ultilizo:
const handleDoubleClick = (index, field) => {
setEditIndex({ index, field });
setEditedValue(arraybalanca[index][field] || "");
};
const handleInputChange = (event) => {
setEditedValue(event.target.value);
};
const handleConfirmEdit = (index, field) => {
const updatedBalanca = [...arraybalanca];
updatedBalanca[index][field] = editedValue.trim();
setArrayBalanca(updatedBalanca);
setEditIndex(null);
setEditedValue("");
};
